KNN-regression vs Linear regression
Is there any assumption on data or any number of k, that makes kNN-regression equivalent to linear regression?

kNN regression will never be exactly equivalent to linear regression; why do you think it would be?

@jbowman It looks like as k increases the  Knn fit gets smoother. I was thinking maybe there is a proof that for k equal to infinity Knn and linear fit does the same

Hmmm...  asymptotically, with $k$ and $n$ increasing?  Good question (+1).

Please add this clarifications in comments as an edit to the post. Comments are easily overseen and can be deleted. Then also add the tag [tag:asymptotics]
